# How to insert data into nested map in c++?

Tags: c++, stl

//I am reading data from file and storing data into structure.Here "obj" is a object of structure.

Also note that my file have outer map key multiple times means when i am reading from file then some field of structure has common value and i am using that common value as a key of outer loop.

If I have only single value of outer key then it works fine but when more than one value of key then it fails.

```
typedef std::map<double,Order_Msg,std::greater<double> >InnerMap;

typedef std::map<int, InnerMap> OuterMap;

InnerMap buy_detailsmap;
OuterMap buy_tokenmap;


//one way
buy_tokenmap.insert(make_pair(obj.token,InnerMap()));
    buy_detailsmap.insert(make_pair(obj.orderId,obj));

//another way

 buy_detailsmap.insert (std::pair<double,Order_Msg>(obj.orderId,obj));
 buy_tokenmap.insert(std::make_pair(obj.token,buy_detailsmap));
```

I tried both but its not working properly.

Comment: Define "its not working properly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear why you need `buy_detailsmap`, as it is de-coupled from `buy_detailsmap`. Unless you really need `insert`'s semantics, you could simply use `operator[]`:

```
buy_tokenmap[obj.token][obj.orderId] = obj;
```

Comment: True. Didn't answer the question, though!